# Hide and show div on click on mobile

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors, hide, show

I'm essentially trying to create an infinite loop of divs on click. It works perfectly on my desktop, but not on mobile browsers. For some reason the divs just  are not appearing on mobile browsers. Here is the jQuery I'm using to loop through the divs:

```
$("div").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
        $(this).hide();
});

$('div').click(function(){
    if ($("div:visible").next().length != 0)
        $("div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
        $("div:visible").hide();
        $("div:first").show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

The CSS for these divs is simple, so no conflict there:

```
div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
}
div img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: while you use .hide() for all divs  where you can find the :visible one??

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Displaying the first div in the CSS, just edited the post. Sorry about that

Comment: even you do that  the jquery will override it and hide all divs .. so instead of .each and loop through divs  just use   $('div:not(:nth-child(1))').hide();  this code will hide all divs but not the 1st one

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef It works on desktop though and does not hide the first div. Maybe adding !important  to display: block to the first div could fix the problem on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

instead of loop through divs

```
// hide all divs but not the :nth-child(1)
$('div:not(:nth-child(1))').hide();
// or
$('div:not(:first)').hide();
```

or its better to do it by css  instead of js

```
div{
   display : none;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
   display: block;
}
```

complete your code then

```
$('div').click(function(){
    if ($("div:visible").next().length !== 0)
        $("div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
        $("div:visible").hide();
        $("div:first").show();
    }
    //return false; no need to use
});
```

Comment: This works on desktop, like the previous model. But it still does not work on mobile. The loop is not infinite, it only goes through once. Then, when you click the last div, everything disappears.

Comment: Whereas, the loop is infinite on desktop browser. Have any clue why?

Comment: @AustinBranham ok I put your code in fiddle please update it with your full code http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/jxuqtfpn/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/daznmjaa/ Here is an updated fiddle with my exact code, with classes applied.

Comment: @AustinBranham its worked well on mobile .. Note 3 .. chrome browser

Comment: Did it really? I'm not sure where my issue is then. I'm going to have to keep searching. It only loops once for me on mobile

Comment: @AustinBranham yes its worked very will like it worked in desktop .. I don't know where your problem is